# OnClick event is not working in coverflow

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager, adapter, coverflow

I have implemented Coverflow ViewPager using https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow it is working good, but the OnClick event is not working from the adapter. I tried a lot but didn't get an succeed, Any one have any idea about it?

My code looks like below

Adapter click listener

```
viewHolder.txtBookNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(activity,ActivityDetail.class);
                activity.startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
```

Adapter xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/cover_selector">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/simple_banner" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPackage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Package"
                    android:textColor="#0288D1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtBookNow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Book Now"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement clicklistner in your activity and try this

```
mCoverFlow = (FeatureCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
        mCoverFlow.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Do what you want
                // list.get(position).titleResId
            }
        });
```

Or In Adapter

```
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("=============== " + mData.get(position).titleResId);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have already used this OnClick on CoverFlow, But I want to perform click on TextView form adapter.

Comment: okey.. than have you tried removing setOnItemClickListener than click on textview??

Comment: Yeah i have removed setOnItemClickListener of CoverFlow and added OnClickListener in Adapter.

Comment: You meant i have to set setOnItemClickListener to CoverFlow and also setOnClickListener in adapter, right?

Comment: @Komal you have to set only `mCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(..)` to CoverFlow. That is fine as per Upendra's answer.

Comment: But If I need to open any activity onClick BookNow TextView and also want to show another activity OnClick Image then how to manage?
Have you an idea?

Comment: But i have checked TextView Click Listener is not working.

Comment: Good.. Keep coding.. enjoy coding.. :-)